# My Eclipse codeing has a dotted in line code

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse codeing has a dotted in line code

[image]

Comment: Switch off visible spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You have 'show whitespace characters' enabled.

Use the 'Window > Editor > Show Whitespace Characters' menu option to change this.

There is also a toolbar button for this:

[image: Toolbar button]

Finally there is a Preference for this: General > Editors > Text Editors > Show whitespace characters. You can configure exactly what is shown there.